# Measure traffic of streaming audio/video in whole office

Tags: performance, internet, measurement

I would like to measure the different traffic used in our office, specifically streaming of audio and video.
I'm trying to assess whether there is any affect of people using streaming on our internet usage.

We have couple of internet connections going out of our offices, I'll be glad to know which equipment is required to measure this.

Comment: If you could specify your current hardware/software/operating systems for network management it would be easier to help you.

Answer (score 2):

You need to gather data at gateway level. If you have a firewall between your LAN and the internet routers, maybe it provide you with the ability to monitor different traffic types.
As another possibly, you can put a routing or bridging Linux machine between your LAN and the routers and use a software like NTOP to monitor network traffic.